# Why Docker doesn't work on my google cloud server?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a VM on Google Cloud.
The endgoal is to run Alphafold 2.

I need docker to create an image from the alphafold2 git page.
I've set up a VM with a 100 GB boot disk.

I try to install docker using the suggested method here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

```
USERNAME@alpha:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package `docker-ce is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

I'm completely lost when it comes to Google Cloud.
Does anyone have a SIMPLE explanation for how to set up Alphafold 2 on Google Cloud?
It is virtually impossible for me since I get error messages when trying to run it using descriptions like this:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-alphafold-with-google-cloud-life-sciences-7219db6ca99e

Comment: Did you add `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`? Then try `sudo apt-get update` after it.

Comment: Why are you installing docker? It's not mentioned the need of installing docker in the article!

Comment: Do not use Docker from the Ubuntu repositories. That version is often too old, or will cause problems later. Use one of the scripts suggested in John Hanley's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following list of commands will install Docker on Ubuntu 20.04. I use to install at the shell prompt and in the startup script to automatically install Docker on virtual machines at the time of creation.

[Reference for installing Docker on Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)

[Install Docker Engine on CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/)

**My script for Ubuntu 20.04:**

```
USERNAME=REPLACE_ME

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install apt-transport-https -y
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt update
sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce -y
sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME
sudo echo "User $USERNAME added to docker group. Re-login to assume docker group membership."
```